# Delta coefficients from mfcc

Tags: mfcc

Can somebody explain to meabout calculating delta coefficients from MFCC for a frame? I didn't understand the interpretation in practical cryptography's tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delta coefficients are the approximate derivatives, so a simple way is to calculate:

```
delta: v(t) = ( c(t+1) - c(t-1) ) / 2
delta-delta: a(t) = c(t-1) - 2 * c(t) + c(t+1)
```

But I have read that in practice, "it is more common to make more sophisticated approximations to the slope, using a wider context of frames" (Jurafsky et al., 2007, Speech and Language Processing) to determine the delta and delta-delta. For example, we might consult a [finite differences table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_coefficient) (we can see that the two values above are the lowest order estimates from those tables, but higher order estimates use more points in the calculations).